# How to send logs from multiple servers to ELK server

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-configuration, filebeat, elk

I have a server in which ELK installed, On other end i have 2 source servers which sending logs to ELK server through filebeat. But the issue is both server's logs showing on same page on kibana. which is too complicated to identify which log is coming from which server! How multiple server's logs show separate on kibana.

Following are my logstash.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

# Used to parse syslog messages and send it to Elasticsearch for storing
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
     grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}" }
  }
     date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
     }
  }
}
# Specify an Elastisearch instance
output {
  Elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Basicly you must have a hostname in field (host.name or something like that depending of your filebeat conf). This field could be use to filter the log by host.

Comment: I have putt my Logstash server's IP as a host.name in my filebeat.yml file